# Capturing response activity within webView

Tags: android, http, webview, httprequest, httpresponse

I have an app which opens a webView page and I need to tap into the HTTP responses of anything that happens within the webView, I couldn't find anything on webView to assist me with that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1776